# Rank condition of block matrices with equivalent row space

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the block matrices $A,B,C$. Let $\operatorname{row}(A) = \operatorname{row}(C)$. Matrices $A,C$ are not necessarily full rank. Is it always true that

\begin{equation}
\operatorname{rank}[A \,\,\, B] = \operatorname{rank}[C \,\,\, B] ?
\end{equation}

I think so, but I don't know how to show this.

Answer (score 1):

It's not true.  Let $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$, $C = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}, B = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$. Clearly $\operatorname{row}(A) = \operatorname{row}(C) = \mathbb{R}^1$, but
\begin{align}
\operatorname{rank}\begin{bmatrix} A & B \end{bmatrix} = 1 < \operatorname{rank}\begin{bmatrix} C & B \end{bmatrix} = 2.  
\end{align}